# Errors after closing stream?

Tags: python, macos, audio

After I close the stream, it is still trying to record and I am getting:

```
(1) Error recording: [Errno Stream closed] -9988
```

A whole bunch of these errors. I told the program to record for 1000 values of volume input. How do I tell it to quit recording, at the same time I close the stream?

Comment: Please provide the shortest possible complete program that demonstrates the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can try exception handling:

```
try:
    # Your code here
except Exception, e:
    print "Error:", e
```